# NestedScrollView not expanding in height inside AlertDialog

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I am currently using a scroll view inside an Alert Dialog and need the scroll view to grow in height until the dialog reaches its maximum default height. It's a bit tough for me to explain so i have attached an illustration to help. Hope it does.

[image]

 
The issue i'm getting is the scrollview does not grow in height and even if i remove the `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/linearLayout4"`, it grows however the bottom part will be partially hidden by the button layout. 
 
 This is my current code :

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/filter_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/dialog_box"
android:minHeight="300dp"
android:elevation="12dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/filter_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/filter"
    style="@style/element_header"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorDark"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/filter_reset_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:text="@string/reset"
    style="@style/text_info_nBold"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/filter_header"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/filter_header" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/linearLayout4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/filter_header"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/filter_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="1000">

        <!-- VIEWS INSIDE HERE -->

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_bottombar_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_secondary_button"
        style="@style/low_emphasis_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/textColorDark"
        android:text="@string/dialog_cancel"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorDark"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_primary_button"
        style="@style/high_emphasis_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/apply" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: "Action Dialog" is new to me. Do you mean an Alert Dialog? The code you use to display the dialog might also be helpful.

Comment: Oh. Sorry i actually made a mistake, its AlertDialog. thank you for pointing that out for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alert dialogs tend to wrap their content or can be forced to be full screen. A size in between the optimizes the screen real estate takes a some work, but it is not impossible.

One approach is to let the system lay out the alert dialog but, before it is displayed, use a *ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener* to examine the resulting size of the dialog. In the layout listener, the size of the dialog can be adjusted up to fit the contents of the scrolling view or adjusted up to full screen if the scrolling view contents are too large for the screen.

Here is a demo app that shows how this can be done. Comments in the code explain more.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        val text = when (v.id) {
            R.id.customDialogShort -> getString(R.string.short_string)
            R.id.customDialogMedium -> getString(R.string.lorem_medium)
            else -> getString(R.string.lorem_long)
        }

        // Specifying the viewGroup as a parent to the inflater makes no difference.
        val dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(v.context).inflate(R.layout.con_custom_view, null, false) as ConstraintLayout
        (dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView).text = text

        val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(dialogView).create()
        val decorView = alertDialog.window!!.decorView
        decorView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alert_dialog_background)

        // We need a layout pass to determine how big everything is and needs to be. Place a hook
        // at the end of the layout process to examine the layout before display.
        decorView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                decorView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)

                // Find out how much of the scrolling view is usable by its child.
                val scrollingView: NestedScrollView = decorView.findViewById(R.id.filter_scroll)
                val scrollingViewPadding = scrollingView.paddingTop + scrollingView.paddingBottom
                val scrollingUsableHeight = scrollingView.height - scrollingViewPadding

                // If the child view fits in the scrolling view, then we are done.
                val childView = scrollingView.getChildAt(0)
                if (childView.height <= scrollingUsableHeight) {
                    return
                }

                // Child doesn't currently fit in the scrolling view. Resize the top-level
                // view so the child either fits or is forced to scroll because the maximum
                // height is reached. First, find out how much space is allowed by the decor view.
                val displayRectangle = Rect()
                decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(displayRectangle)
                val decorViewPadding = decorView.paddingTop + decorView.paddingBottom
                val decorUsableHeight = displayRectangle.height() - decorViewPadding - scrollingViewPadding

                // Compute the height of the dialog that will 100% fit the scrolling content and
                // reduce it if it won't fit in the maximum allowed space.
                val heightToFit = dialogView.height + childView.height - scrollingUsableHeight
                dialogView.minHeight = min(decorUsableHeight, heightToFit)
            }
        })
        var buttonOk: Button = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_primary_button)
        buttonOk.setOnClickListener { alertDialog.dismiss() }
        buttonOk = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_secondary_button)
        buttonOk.setOnClickListener { alertDialog.dismiss() }
        alertDialog.show()
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/customDialogShort"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Short text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/customDialogMedium"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Medium text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/customDialogLong"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Long text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**con_custom_view**
Custom Layout for the AlertDialog.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filter_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/filter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/filter_reset_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:text="@string/reset"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/filter_header"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/filter_header" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/filter_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:scrollbarFadeDuration="1000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/linearLayout4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/filter_header">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="@string/lorem_long" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_secondary_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dialog_cancel"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_primary_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/apply" />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I am using java, have not transitioned to kotlin yet so im finding your code slightly challenging. What do mean here "dialogView.minHeight = min(decorUsableHeight, heightToFit)" are you calling the Math.min function ?

Comment: Please share your xml file for the dialog layout

Comment: @jeanlucrotolo [Here](https://gist.github.com/Cheticamp/48dccb7b906e06471591c784a8b295ba) is the Java version. I post the custom layout in the answer.

Comment: Sorry but it does not work as shown in the video. There is no change to the layout after i call dialog.setMinimumHeight()

Comment: @jeanlucrotolo It's `dialogView.setMinHeight()` to set the minimum height in _ConstraintLayout_.

Comment: Yes, i mistakenly set the dialog variable to a View object. It works now.

Comment: Great solution! I used it in `DialogFragment`